# Cloud-init: how to install it from the source code?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, cloud-init

I have a `Ubuntu 1604` VM on `Azure`, which by default has `cloud-init` installed.

To debug a cloud-init issue, I removed the default cloud-init (`apt remove cloud-init`) and cloned the source code from `https://git.launchpad.net/cloud-init/` and want to build my version of cloud-init to debug.

Could you please help me:

1. How to **compile** cloud-init from the source code tree?
2. How to **install** cloud-init from my local source?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was pleased to find that, even though it is terribly [un]documented, it is easy to clone, build, and install the latest.

```
git clone https://github.com/cloud-init/cloud-init.git
cd cloud-init
sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt 
sudo python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install --init-system systemd
sudo cloud-init init --local
sudo cloud-init status

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cloud-init /usr/bin/cloud-init
for svc in cloud-init-local.service cloud-init.service cloud-config.service cloud-final.service; do
  sudo systemctl enable $svc
  sudo systemctl start  $svc
done
```

I haven’t managed to use this new version yet. I will [continue to] update this answer if there are additional considerations.

Note:
I am working on a demo that would use `user-data` and `meta-data` files in `/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/`

Credit: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB27U_6.4.0/com.ibm.zvm.v640.hcpo5/instsubuntu.htm

Comment: Even though this post is a few years old it worked for me installing v22.1 tag on CE7. I just needed to change `distro: centos` in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg`